# file based data provider

Tags: java

here is my scenario. In my Junit tests, in many places, I need to provide user name, description, url, invalid url etc. So I hard coded those values. It is not good to hard code everywhere. So I want to move those values to a centralized place (a file). And I have some data provider say DP. I can call DP.getUserName(), DP.getUrl() etc. at places where need those values. Also, I want to have a pool of different user names, urls, invalid urls etc. When I call getUrl, it will randomly pick up on from the pool.

What I can think of is to use java.util.Properties to load propertis from a file and each time I call, I just randomly return one entry.

Any better approach to achieve this goal? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A properties file is a good idea, also allows you to not have to recompile code when a item changes. The getUrl pulling from a pool is fine.

However, if you have several getUserName(), getErrorURL(), getDatabaseName(), etc. that all return a String. You might want to think about storing those single key-value properties in a map in your DP class and provide some a public enum list to access variables.

Something like:

```
 private Map<PROP, String> map;
 public enum PROP{ USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE_NAME};

 public String getProperty(PROP key){
     return map.get(key);
 }
```

That way you don't have to add a new method and variable for each property;

Comment: thanks for the comment. How do I support a pool of user names, urls etc? Since property file is key/value pair. The property file will look like: USERNAME1=Tom

Comment: One way is to use a delimited and split them up when you load them:  INVALIDS=bob|tom|randy

Comment: When you instantiate that `Map`, you'll probably want to use an `EnumMap`.

Comment: I am a little hesitated about the delimit and split approach. Because my url, description or name can be a relatively long string and may contain many different characters to test different cases. If I concatenate them into a single string, my property file may look messy and hard to edit by hand. thanks!

Comment: create different .properties files for each entry in your pool...  or use the suffixed number approach - that is certainly legit, and easy to do.